# ocamlfind complains no implementation provided for modules installed through opam

Tags: ocaml, ocamlfind

I was messing around with the OCaml FFI to try to figure out how it goes about inferring the width of a C enum (which I think is implementation-defined for C) and am trying to insert a type of the wrong width to see what blows up at runtime. That's the motivation, but the actual issue I ran into is much more mundane.

I have a simple OCaml file that uses the C FFI to call a trivial function in `example.c` that converts an enum to an int.

```
open Printf;;

let (@->) = Ctypes.(@->);;
let returning = Ctypes.returning;;

let foreign = Foreign.foreign;;

(* deliberately use the wrong scalar type for argument *)
let wrong_int64_of_color =
  foreign "int_of_color" (Ctypes.int64_t @-> returning Ctypes.int64_t);;

let main () =
  printf "%Ld\n" (wrong_int64_of_color (Int64.of_int 100));;

let () = main ();;
```

I configured opam and installed `Ctypes` and `Ctypes.Foreign`

```
    % opam config env | sed -e 's/=.*/=/'
CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
OPAMUTF8MSGS=
MANPATH=
PERL5LIB=
OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH=
PATH=

% opam list | grep ctypes
ctypes                      0.6.2  Combinators for binding to C libraries withou
ctypes-foreign              0.4.0  Virtual package for enabling the ctypes.forei
```

The two usual incantations I use for compiling a simple `.ml` script have both failed me and I'm out of ideas. `ocamlfind` and `corebuild` (which I think is a wrapper on top of `ocamlbuild`)

ocamlfind can't seem to find `ctypes` and `foreign`. However, it doesn't complain that about not being able to locate the packages so I'm guessing `ctypes` and `ctypes.foreign` are the correct names for these packages in the weird `findlib` namespace.

```
% ocamlfind ocamlopt -package findlib,ctypes,ctypes.foreign -thread call_example.ml
File "_none_", line 1:
Warning 58: no cmx file was found in path for module Foreign, and its interface was not compiled with -opaque
File "call_example.ml", line 1:
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
         Ctypes referenced from call_example.cmx
         Foreign referenced from call_example.cmx
```

Why can't `ocamlfind` locate these modules? I have no problem loading them into the toplevel.

```
─( 22:30:42 )─< command 0 
utop # #require "ctypes";;
─( 22:30:42 )─< command 1 
utop # open Ctypes;;
─( 22:30:55 )─< command 2 
utop # #require "ctypes.foreign";;
─( 22:31:00 )─< command 3 
utop # open Ctypes;;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that you forget to add `-linkpkg` ocamlfind option to instruct the compiler actually link the libraries from the packages to build the executable.